# How can I make the data image link in ASP.NET temporary

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an old ASP.NET application. We have an image element on one of the pages. For the security purpose we would like to stream the image instead of a direct reference. However, after the data link is generated from the stream, it appears to be permanent. Even after the application is closed, the data link is still alive.

Is there a way to make this link invalid when out of session, to somehow invalidate it, by maybe emptying a stream?

Please let me know

Thank you in advance

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    string physicalPath = "some path of an image";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fs.CopyTo(ms);
    }

    img.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Length);
```

Comment: Well, no.  The link doesn't interact with the server at all.  The link itself *contains* all of the data needed to render the image.  You can't invalidate it after giving all of the data to the client.  It sounds like perhaps you don't want to use a `data` URL but instead want an actual URL to a server-side resource which returns the file when requested.  (Keep in mind browsers can and will still cache that data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

Changes the above code to

```
 Session["ImageStream"] = true;
 img.ImageUrl = "MyImage.aspx";
```

Where the code for the MyImage.aspx is

```
   protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (Session["ImageStream"] != null && (bool)Session["ImageStream"])
        {
            string somePath = "Some path";
            byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(somePath);
            Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You may consider placing a javascript code that change the  element "src" attribute when the session is expired.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately the user can always copy the actual location of an image before the src changes

Comment: But user can do the screenshot while his session is active. When you showing something to the user, it cannot be assumed under your control anymore.